# setData on button click for CKEditor 5 in React

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm using CKEditor 5 as a text editor in a React app. I have a button on a page which when clicked will insert the text "Button was clicked" inside the CkEditor. How can i achieve this? I know CKEditor has the setData method but how will my button click even be able to access the CKEditor?

My ckeditor

```
<CKEditor editor={ClassicEditor} />
```

My button

```
<Button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</Button>
```

handleClick

```
handleClick = e => { /* setData in the editor */ };
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

Before Handle click in ckEditor declaration you need to handle onInit method.

In onInit method CkEditor will give you an instance of editor. You need to save this instance in your local variable.

Step 2:
inside handle click you can use this:

```
 editor.model.change(writer => {
            writer.insertText("Button was clicked", editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition());
        });
```